# How devise include generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

How devise include their generators like `devise:install` without the creation of `lib/generator` inside the rails project?

I mean, what is the magic here? Is the `require_paths = ["lib"]` who does the trick including the generators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the gem, there is a 'generator' folder structure that rails looks for

```
lib/generators/devise...
```

In `devise.gemspec`, the `lib` dir is added to the require path:

```
s.require_paths = ["lib"]
```

This means that once you add devise to your `Gemfile`, rails now has access to it's generators because they follow the structure and naming conventions rails expects.

Here is the [install generator](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/devise/install_generator.rb) for your reference. If you were to rename that file to `installer_generator.rb` and change the class name to `InstallerGenerator`, the devise install command would then become `rails g devise:installer` instead of `rails g devise:install`

Hopefully this helps clear things up.